# vue.js - get the index of the object when value changed

Tags: vuejs2

I have this data:

```
products:[
{'name':'product1', 'price':'','syntax':'true'},
{'name':'product2', 'price':'','syntax':'true'},
{'name':'product3', 'price':'','syntax':'true'}
]
```

Which I need to watch for the price change:

```
watch:{
        products:{
            handler: function (val, oldVal) {
                console.log(this.products);
            },
            deep: true
            }
        }
```

Which works fine. However, I want to know which `product.price` has been changed when it is changing, so that I can check with `regex` and set if the `product.syntax` is true or false. How can I get the `index` of the `products` in the `watch`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
watch: {
    products: {
        handler: function (val, oldVal) {

            var vm = this;
            let changed = val.filter( function( product, index ) {
                return Object.keys(product).some( function( prop ) {
                return product[prop] !== vm.$data.oldVal[index][prop];
            })

            console.log(changed)
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

Comment: got error: `Error in callback for watcher "products": "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
watch: {
    products: {
        handler(newVal, oldVal) {
            let changedIndex;
            newVal.forEach((product, idx) => {
                if (product.price !== oldVal[idx].price) {
                    changedIndex = idx;
                }
            })
            console.log(changedIndex);
        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    products:[
      {'name':'product1', 'price': '0','syntax':'true'},
      {'name':'product2', 'price': '3','syntax':'true'},
      {'name':'product3', 'price': '10','syntax':'true'}
    ]
  },
  watch: {
    products: {
      handler(newVal, oldVal) {
        newVal.forEach(product => {
          if (parseInt(product.price) > 5) {
            product.syntax = true;
          } else {
            product.syntax = false;
          }
        })
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>Syntax changes to true when price > 5</span>
  <table>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Syntax</th>
    <tr v-for="(product, idx) in products">
      <td>{{product.name}}</td>
      <td><input type="text" v-model="product.price"/></td>
      <td>{{product.syntax}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I just test your code and it did not work. I `console.log` both `val` and `oldVal`, both of them return the same value. Strangely in `vuejs` documentation, they use the same example.

Comment: Okay, give me some time to whip up a working example. But first, are those prices modified through user input?